# Speeding up nested for loop that utilizes 2 large arraylists

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

Have 2 arraylists of objects in which the 2nd one has a related field that i want to populate the first one with.

```
public ArrayList<object1> updateAccountWithGSAM(ArrayList<object1> o1, ArrayList<object2> o2) {
    ArrayList<object1> accs = new ArrayList<object1>();

    for (object1 acc : o1) {
        ArrayList<String> o2s= new ArrayList<String>();
        for (object2 g : o2) {
            if (g.getfield() != null) {
                if (acc.getId().equals(g.getobject1())) {
                    o2s.add(g.getCode());
                }
            }

        }
        acc.setGSAM_code(o2s);
        accs.add(acc);
    }


    return accs;

}
```

In general this works fine when the data is small, but this encounters issues when data sets get large (obj1 and 2 are about 500,000 in size each in prod).

Not sure what optimizations I can do to speed this up or is there an alternative to nested for loops for what I'm trying to accomplish?

Comment: what version of java you are using? If Java 8, try streams

Comment: You could put that data into two maps, using that id as key. Saves you the n times 2 looping.

Comment: I'm on java 8. But not too familiar with streams pons, Is this a valid option for filtering between 2 lists?

Comment: I am glad that my input got you to write your own working solution. If you found my input helpful I wouldn't mind if you upvote another answer of mine. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't compiled the code but, something like  this should work:

```
public ArrayList<object1> updateAccountWithGSAM(ArrayList<object1> o1, ArrayList<object2> o2) {
   HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> reverseMap = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>()
    for (object2 g : o2) {
        if (g.getfield() != null) {
            ArrayList<String> accs1 = reverseMap.get(g.getobject1());
            if(accs1 == null) {
                accs1 = new ArrayList<String>()
                reverseMap.put(g.getobject1(), acc1)
            }
            accs1.add(o2s);
        }
    }
    ArrayList<object1> accs = new ArrayList<object1>();
    for (object1 acc : o1) {
        ArrayList<String> o2s= new ArrayList<String>();
        if(reverseMap.get(acc.getCode()) != null) {
            acc.setGSAM_code(o2s);
            accs.add(acc);
        }
    }

    return accs;
}
```

Comment: This would be my first attempt at optimization too (the size might start to make other map types more attractive). It reduces the need to do the costly search over o2 once per item in o1.

Comment: haha I ended up writing something almost exactly like this based off the suggestion from ghostcat. Works like a charm!